# How to use Arrays.sort method to sort a 2D integer array in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a 2D integer array of

```
int[][] arr = new int [][] {
            {1,1},
            {2,222},
            {3,32},
            {4,13},
            {5,1144},
            {6,111},
            {7,12341},
            {8,111}
        };
```

I want to sort this array in an increasing order of second element of each row.

```
[[1, 1], [4, 13], [3, 32], [8, 111], [6, 111], [2, 222], [5, 1144], [7, 12341]]
```

But notice, when the second element's values are same as in

```
[8, 111] and [6, 111]
```

The sorting order reversed.

So here is what I attempted

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> a[1]==b[1]? b[1]-a[1]: a[1]-b[1]);
```

Whenever second elements are equal, reverse the sorting order to descending order, otherwise keep the ascending order.

After running this code, I get a result of

```
[[1, 1], [4, 13], [3, 32], [6, 111], [8, 111], [2, 222], [5, 1144], [7, 12341]]
```

Notice how the

```
 [6, 111], [8, 111]
```

are still in the wrong order.

Comment: Note how `a[1]==b[1]? b[1]-a[1] :a[1]-b[1]` will always be `0` or `a[1]-b[1]` (`a[1]==b[1]? b[1]-a[1]` is always `0`)

Comment: I don't fully understand but you probably need `Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> a[1]==b[1]? b[0]-a[0]: a[1]-b[1]);` If second elements are equal, compare first elements i.e. elements at 0th index.

Comment: Your reported output after the change shows a different order but you claim it is the same.

Comment: Are you saying you want a _stable sort_? That's already what the Java sorting algorithm does, if you just sort on the second element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Integer.compare method:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> a[1]==b[1]?
                          Integer.compare(b[0], a[0]):
                          Integer.compare(a[1], b[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe  this?

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> a[1]==b[1]? b[0]-a[0]: a[1]-b[1])
```

Comment: Comparing using subtraction can result in overflow. You'd think that Integer.MAX_VALUE is bigger than Integer.MIN_VALUE, but `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE` is negative.

Comment: It is very bad technique to subtract values to satisfy the `Comparator` contract.  Try it with values near Integer.MIN_VALUE and Integer.MAX_VALUE and see what you get.  Always return 1, -1, or 0. or use `Integer.compare() or Integer.compareTo()`

Answer (score 2):

I would try it like this using a Comparator.  If you want the first numbers in ascending order, then remove the reverseOrder comparator.  Otherwise, leave it in. If you want to leave the first numbers in their relatively same positions when the second numbers are equal, then just sort on the second number.  This will work since the sorting algorithm is stable.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a) -> a[1])
        .thenComparing(a -> a[0], Comparator.reverseOrder()));

for (int[] a : arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 1]
[4, 13]
[3, 32]
[8, 111]
[6, 111]
[2, 222]
[5, 1144]
[7, 12341]
```

Comment: It's a pity there's no `thenComparingInt(function, comparator)` which forces you to write `thenComparing` instead, or using the technique in my answer to avoid boxing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a) -> a[1])
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a) -> a[0]).reversed()));
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, `reversed()` actually reverses every comparator that precedes it.  But since you put in a Comparator within the `thenComparing` method, it worked.  It's a subtlety that I have found that most are not aware of.